# Access rowid in SQLite table which contains columns named 'rowid', '_rowid_', and 'oid'

Tags: sqlite

> [The rowid value can be accessed using one of the special case-independent names "rowid", "oid", or "_rowid_" in place of a column name. If a table contains a user defined column named "rowid", "oid" or "_rowid_", then that name always refers the explicitly declared column and cannot be used to retrieve the integer rowid value.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

If a table contains all of those columns (and none are `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`), is there a way to refer to the rowid value? (Of course, such a table would be very badly designed, but I am writing a generic utility and so "change the schema" is not an answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the special names are already taken, and if there is no `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to create a new name, then it is not possible at all to refer to the rowid value.

(Such a table would be encountered by your program only if somebody wanted to break it, so give them what they want and let your program crash in the most spectacular way. )

<sup>(And don't forget to handle [WITHOUT ROWID](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html) tables correctly.)</sup>